# Sql. Return rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Person table.
Each person can have many names in the PersonNames table.
I would like to get for each person, 2 of his first names and 2 of his last names in one row.
like this:

```
PersonId | FName1 | Fname2  | Lname1    | Lname2
1          David    Daniekl   Bekernman   Stivens
```

**Person** table:

```
   PersonId
   BirthDate
```

**PersonNames** table:

```
   PersonId
   NameId
   Name
   NameType (e.g; first, last...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are `Person` and `PersonNames` related? Is there a `PersonId` in `PersonNames` that you've not shown?

Comment: Yes there is a PersonId in personNames.

Comment: Can you give us the example PersonNames table for your Person?

Comment: And what variety of SQL?  MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, SQLite, etc?

Comment: Ready, see attached answer with the demo data inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a little detour through a XML column.

```
;with P(PersonID, Names) as 
(
  select PersonID,
         (select NameType as '@NameType',
                 Name as '*'
          from PersonNames as PN 
          where PN.PersonId = P.PersonId
          for xml path('Name'), type)
  from Person as P
)
select P.PersonID,
       P.Names.value('(/Name[@NameType = "first"])[1]', 'varchar(100)') as FName1,
       P.Names.value('(/Name[@NameType = "last"])[1]', 'varchar(100)') as LName1,
       P.Names.value('(/Name[@NameType = "first"])[2]', 'varchar(100)') as FName2,
       P.Names.value('(/Name[@NameType = "last"])[2]', 'varchar(100)') as LName2
from P
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/123608/

Comment: Why the XML, and not just a straight MAX() *[my answer]* or a PIVOT *[AndriyM's answer]*?  Are there peformance characterisitic differences?

Comment: @Dems - I just wanted to show a different way to get the job done. I have not tested this for performance so I really don't know. It really depends on the number of rows returned. The where clause should to filter rows should be applied in the CTE for best performance. I would not recommend to make this query in to a view and use that in joins etc. It would probably generate the entire CTE for every question regardless if one row is output or all rows. If performance is an issue I would recommend to do a straight query and the pivot on the client for presentation.

Comment: @Dems BTW. This solution is very similar to the popular `for xml path` trick to concatenate rows in to comma separated strings.

Comment: @Dems - I looked a bit on both yours and AndriyM's answer and both get the job done in a single table scan. Without a where clause that is a good as it gets. +1 to you both.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: I wished I could have as much discerning with your answer as you had with mine! For me, your answer is primarily useful because it contains a correctly working solution that uses XML, a thing that I know poorly at the moment. Being rather lazy to learn by extensively reading the docs, I'm presently trying to gather as much as possible by looking at various examples. (It is very often with me so that, once there's a basic understanding of the principle in my head, it produces quite a natural desire to obtain more theoretical knowledge on the matter.)

Answer (score 4):

If this is *specifically* for just two names, this will pick up the names with the MIN and MAX NameId per Person...

```
SELECT
  Person.PersonId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name.nameId = map.minNameId AND Name.nameType = 'first' THEN Name.Name ELSE NULL END) AS fname1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name.nameId = map.minNameId AND Name.nameType = 'last'  THEN Name.Name ELSE NULL END) AS lname1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name.nameId = map.maxNameId AND Name.nameType = 'first' THEN Name.Name ELSE NULL END) AS fname2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name.nameId = map.maxNameId AND Name.nameType = 'last'  THEN Name.Name ELSE NULL END) AS lname2
FROM
  Person
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT personId, MIN(nameId) AS minNameId, MAX(nameId) as maxNameId FROM PersonNames GROUP BY PersonId) AS map
    ON map.PersonId = Person.PersonId
LEFT JOIN
  PersonNames AS Name
    On Name.PersonId = Person.PersonId
GROUP BY
  Person.PersonId
```

**EDIT**

Now that I can see that this is MS SQL Server, there is another option.  Similar to others here, but possibly slightly simpler...

```
WITH
  sequenced_names AS
(
  SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY NameID) AS NameOrdinal,
    *
  FROM
    PersonNames
)
SELECT
  PersonID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN nameOrdinal = 1 AND nameType = 'first' THEN Name END) AS fname1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN nameOrdinal = 1 AND nameType = 'last'  THEN Name END) AS lname1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN nameOrdinal = 2 AND nameType = 'first' THEN Name END) AS fname2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN nameOrdinal = 2 AND nameType = 'last'  THEN Name END) AS lname2
FROM
  sequenced_names
GROUP BY
  PersonID
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this. You say it's for just two names – for *two names per person* or *for two names of each type per person* (i.e. for four names)? The reason for my question is the fact that you are pulling *four* names in the final select, but you are only mapping exactly *two* `nameId`s per `personId`, irrespectively of `nameType`. Either I am missing something or there's an oversight on your side.

Comment: @AndriyM - Two Names (identified by a NameID) composed of two parts (a first name and a last name, identified by NameType).

Comment: Ah, I can see now the reason of my incomprehension! From the original post, I've gathered that *all* the (partial) names linked to the same `personId` constitute a single name. But you seem to view them as (possibly) several names, each pair of one first and one last names constituting a separate alternative name of the associated `personId` – is that so?

Comment: Thanks, I only meant to make my understanding of your approach more exact. There's no question of whose assumption is more easily wrong until there's more information on the matter. I fixed on mine as soon as I read the first few sentences: I remembered an article I once read about how really, really long a Portuguese name can be, of which I'm still under impression. Apparently you were free from associations of the kind when making your assumption.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way of solving this as I can see it, is to rank every person's names of each type independently with different ranking signs, i.e. for instance, first names with positive rankings, last names with negative ones. Then you pick and pivot names that have rankings of `1`, `2`, `-1`, `-2`. Here's what the query might look like:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk =
      CASE NameType WHEN 'first' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END *
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY PersonId, NameType
        ORDER BY NameId
      )
  FROM PersonNames
  WHERE NameType IN ('first', 'last')
)
SELECT
  PersonId,
  FName1   = [1],
  FName2   = [2],
  LName1   = [-1],
  LName2   = [-2]
FROM (
  SELECT
    PersonId,
    Name,
    rnk
  FROM ranked
) s
PIVOT (
  MAX(Name) FOR rnk IN ([-2], [-1], [1], [2])
) p
```

On the other hand, ranking last names from the end might appear more appropriate (at least, I think, *I* might prefer it better this way). So here's an alternative to the above script which ranks last names from the end:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk =
      CASE NameType WHEN 'first' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END *
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY PersonId, NameType
        ORDER BY CASE NameType WHEN 'first' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * NameId
      )
  FROM PersonNames
  WHERE NameType IN ('first', 'last')
),
SELECT
  PersonId,
  FName1   = [1],
  FName2   = [2],
  LName1   = ISNULL([-2], [-1]),
  LName2   = CASE WHEN [-2] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [-1] END
FROM (
  SELECT
    PersonId,
    Name,
    rnk
  FROM ranked
) s
PIVOT (
  MAX(Name) FOR rnk IN ([-2], [-1], [1], [2])
) p
```

You can see that this version is a bit more complicated. For one thing, a change of sign had to be applied to `NameId` to ensure its sorting in different directions for different types.

Another thing is pulling the final result set. You see, if a person has just two or more last names, the script would display them in the order as they are in the table: the item before the last goes to `LName1` and the last item goes to `LName2`. But in case of exactly one last name my intention was to display it as `LName1`, and `LName2` to be empty (just like the first query would do). Therefore, as you can see, additional measures had to be taken to ensure that order of display.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, SQL Server solution,

Assuming there is also PersonId column in table OF names and there is no more than 2 names for each person, else we need subqueries here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
[PersonId] [int] PRIMARY KEY
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonNames]
(
[PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
[nameId] [int] NOT NULL,
[NAME] [varchar] (100) NOT NULL,
[NameType] [varchar] (10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT Person VALUES(1),(2)

INSERT dbo.PersonNames(PersonId, NameId, Name, NameType)
SELECT 1,1,'John', 'first' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,'Doe', 'last' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,'Ioann', 'first' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,'Doeman', 'last' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3,'Yonh', 'first' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3,'Doesson', 'last' UNION ALL

SELECT 2,1,'John2', 'first' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'Doe2', 'last' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,'Ioann2', 'first' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,'Doeman2', 'last' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3,'Yonh2', 'first' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3,'Doesson2', 'last' 


SELECT 
    Person.PersonId, 
    FName1.NAME FName1,
    LName1.NAME LName1,
    FName2.NAME FName2,
    LName2.NAME LName2
FROM Person
JOIN (
       SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY NameId) Ordinal,
        PersonId, Name, NameId
       FROM PersonNames 
       WHERE  NameType = 'first'
     ) FName1
    ON FName1.PersonId = Person.PersonId AND FName1.Ordinal=1
JOIN PersonNames LName1
    ON LName1.PersonId = FName1.PersonId AND LName1.NameType = 'last' AND FName1.NameId = LName1.NameId
LEFT JOIN 
     (
       SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY NameId) Ordinal,
        PersonId, Name, NameId
       FROM PersonNames 
       WHERE  NameType = 'first' 
     ) FName2
    ON FName2.PersonId = Person.PersonId AND FName2.NameId <> FName1.NameId AND FName2.Ordinal = 2
LEFT JOIN PersonNames LName2
    ON FName2.PersonId = LName2.PersonId AND LName2.NameType = 'last' AND LName2.NameId <> LName1.NameId AND FName2.NameId = LName2.NameId

DROP TABLE Person
DROP TABLE dbo.PersonNames
```

Comment: Very elegant.  Wish I had thought of that :)

Comment: If the person has two first names in the table, the first join will find both.  This will led to two records with different names in different columns.  Also, if the person has more than two first names, the first left join will pick all of them except one, again causing duplication.

Comment: Due to the `TOP 1`, this will now only work for one person in the Person table, and there is no guarantee that the second `TOP 1` will be for the same person.

Comment: This still has the same issues, but now has one more - You can't JOIN on a correlated sub-query.  If the variety of SQL has an APPLY operator that could be used in this way...  *To fix the second issue, order both sub-queries by PersonID, NameID.  The "works for only one person" can't be corrected with this layout.*

Comment: @OlegDok - Slighty over-wieldy, bu -1 removed as I think it does now work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat in mysql to put them in a single row, then your application can determine which to display.

```
SELECT Person.PersonId
     , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT first_name.Name SEPARATOR ',' ) AS first_names
     , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT last_name.Name SEPARATOR ',' ) AS last_names
FROM Person
LEFT JOIN PersonName first_name ON Person.PersonId = first_name.PersonId AND first_name.Type = 'first'
LEFT JOIN PersonName last_name ON Person.PersonId = last_name.PersonId AND last_name.Type = 'last'
GROUP BY Person.PersonId
```

You can also use SUBSTRING and LOCATE in SQL to grab the first and second entry in first and last, but the method is rather brittle/complicated.

Comment: NOTE: this *assumes* MySQL.  Also, it has an issue...  If there are 2 first names and 2 last names, the two left JOINs will yield 4 records with the different combinations...  [ (f1,l1) (f1,l2) (f2,l1) (f2,l2) ] and so cause duplication in the GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Duplication is removed by the 'DISTINCT' keyword